# Laravel Middleware / Route Groups

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I'm fairly new to Laravel, so this question may obvious to some.

In the case of running checks per HTTP request, for example *User Authentication*. Is there a better, more efficient or simple correct way to run these checks. From my initial research it would seem that this could be accomplished using either MiddleWare, eg.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

It also seems like it would be possible using routing groups, eg.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ()    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function () {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });
});
```

Is there any benefits of doing this either of these two ways? Apart from the obvious benefit of not having to put `$this->middleware('auth');` in every controller auth would need to be checked.

Thanks

### Edit..

After taking on your advice I attempted to utilities the route grouping to control my Auth MiddleWare. But this has seemed to have broken my site.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

    Route::get ( '/redirect/{provider}', 'SocialAuthController@redirect' );
    Route::get ( '/callback/{provider}', 'SocialAuthController@callback' );
});
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: It does the same thing, so pick whatever way you prefer, and stick to it

Comment: So they have absolutely no difference?

Comment: `Route::auth ();` is just a stortcut for declaring all the routes used for registration and login. If you use s decent IDE you can click and go to the method definition, which will show you the routes being created. Laravel uses a lot of abstraction, magic methods and multiple inheritance, so a good ide is a must really

Comment: Could you suggest a good idea to use with Laravel?

Comment: Phpstorm if you are willing to spend a few quid , Netbeans if you are not.

Comment: Ive made an edit regarding utilising the MiddleWare

Comment: The auth routes have to be outside the middleware. As you currently have it, you need to be logged in to access the login form!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119014/discussion-between-scottevans93-and-steve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Route group is easy for maintenance/modification , other wise you will have to remember each controller where you are using certain middle ware, of course this not a concern in a small medium sized application, but this will be hard in a large application where is lots of controller and references to middle ware.

Comment: got the source from `https://vi.stackfinder.net/questions/38745291/laravel-middleware-route-groups`

Answer (score 3):

The suggested options did not work for me but when I checked the laravel documentation, I found this:

```
Route::middleware(['web'])->group(function () {
    //Your routes here
});
```

It works for me. Laravel 8.*

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, just remove the `Route::auth()`:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    //add more Routes here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no real difference, personally i use groups for the standard middleware and put exceptions in the construct

Comment: a middleware used only once or twice, age gate for a specific page for example